# Sonicwall default details / hard reset

Tags: sonicwall

I have tried to hard reset a (recently aquired) old sonicwall tz100 but I'm not sure it's working.

I have used the pin hole on the back and tried it both while on and while I plug it in.

The model is APL22-07F.

When I connect to it it's giving me an ip in the 10.0.10.0 range and it's own ip is 10.0.10.5.

I was expecting an ip of 192.168.168.168.

I can see the login screen but the default password of admin and password does not work.

Do I have the incorrect login details or is it not resetting?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your firewall was not reset correctly: default (post-reset) settings are 192.168.168.168 and admin/password as credentials.

Try resetting in this manner:

```
 - power off the device
 - press and keep presed the reset button
 - at the same time (it's a bit tricky), power on the device
 - wait 60 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset button was bent inside box.

Opened it, pushed back, reset properly.

Cheers